# Specman DAC macro: How to define 2 inputs of different type (uint and string)?

Tags: macros, specman, e

in my verification environment I have different registers' types with almost the same name that differs only by index, e.g.: `timer_load_0`, `timer_load_1` etc..
I try to create a macro that gets 2 parameters: `string` (the 'name' of the register without its index) and `uint` (the register's index) and returns a variable of "concatenated" register type.
For example I would like that the command:

```
my_idx : uint = 0;
create_reg "timer_load" my_idx;
```

will return the variable `timer_load_0`.

**My macro code**:

```
define <var_by_idx'action> "create_reg <name'any> <idx'exp>" as computed {
    var idx : uint = <idx'exp>.as_a(uint);
    result = appendf("%s_%d",<name'any>, idx);  
};
```

The compilation error I get:

```
Error: Looking for a number but found 'my_idx'
                at line 45 in @macros
    var idx : uint = <idx'exp>.as_a(uint);
                during execution of a define-as-computed macro:
                at line 380 in @timer_monitor
            create_reg "timer_load" my_idx;
```

The macro does not recognize `my_idx` as `uint` variable but as `string`..
Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve by this macro. In general, a DAC macro is executed during parsing (not at run time), and it should usually return some string, which contains some legal e code, and which is further parsed. In this example, I don't see the macro returns any string.
Could you please clarify what exactly are you trying to do here? What is expected to happen at run time?

Comment: Hi Yuri, I've edited my question with fixes according to your notes

Comment: I think I kind of get what you want to do here from the questions you've been previously asking. You probably have the same field defined in both sub-types and you just need to cast to be able to access it. You could use reflection in this case, but it's going to be costlier in terms of run-time performance, I think.

Comment: If that's the case, then maybe you could post another question with some more context.

Answer (score 2):

A macro that does what you want can only be passed a constant value, so you would need to change back to `<idx'num>`.

As Yuri mentioned, define as computed macros are expanded at compile time. This means your macro needs to get a constant value for `idx` to know what type of variable to allocate for your `created_reg`. The value of the `idx` variable you would want to pass to the macro is only set at run-time, which is just too late.

Comment: Hi Tudor, I've edited the question and i've fixed the code with as_a(uint), but I still has compilation error..

Comment: @Halona I just realized that what you want is impossible, because you need to know at compile time what sub-type you want (TIMER_LOAD_0 or TIMER_LOAD_1). You can't use a variable for this.

Comment: Even if the macro was used with a constant (such as 'create_reg "timer_load" 1'), it's still not clear what's the expected outcome. The macro is declared to be <action>, but 'timer_load_1' is not an action. So, what should it actually do? Declare a field? Declare a local variable? Anything else?

Comment: @YuriTsoglin I think he wants to get a certain register instance from a reg file and then cast it to a certain sub-type and store it in a variable of that type.